# AJAX: $(this) on event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two files, one contains the html and javascript code and the other one contains texts. It works but only on the first div because I specified it on the javascript code. Now I would like to display the text only on the clicked element. I would like to use the $(this) property but how ?

HTML code

```
<div id="ajax">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>list 1</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="link">show</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Another list</li>
            <li>Another list 2</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="link">show</a>        
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
var username = "username";
var message = "This is my message";

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    var btn = btns[i];
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    $('#ajax div ul')[0].append(li);
                    document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].lastChild.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?username='+username+'&msg='+message, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

    })
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Marcel, what do you mean by "I would like to use the $(this) property" ?

Comment: If your using jQuery why are you not using $.ajax, jquery selectors and event handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your code I have made some changes, I hope it is not an inconvenience:

```js
var username = "username";
var message = "This is my message";

$('.link').click((e) => {
  
  var divContext = $(e.target).parent();
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

      divContext.find("li:last").after("<li></li>");
      divContext.find("li:last").append(xmlhttp.responseText);
        
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?username='+username+'&msg='+message, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ajax">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>list 1</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="link">show</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Another list</li>
            <li>Another list 2</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="link">show</a>        
    </div>

</div>
```

**1)** I replaced `var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.link');` and `btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){` whit `$('.link').click((e) => {`

**2)** If you look into the click function, you'll can see this line **var divContext = $(e.target).parent();**, **$(e.target)** is equivalent to **$(this)** in arrow function with jquery. If don't like arrow function you can use it this way:

```
$('.link').click(function() {

      var divContext = $(this).parent();
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            divContext.find("li:last").after("<li></li>");
            divContext.find("li:last").append(xmlhttp.responseText);

        }
      }

      xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?username='+username+'&msg='+message, true);
      xmlhttp.send();

});
```

Comment: Great @Marcel, can you put my answer like correct please? thanks

Comment: it's done. The second method is more effective. Thanks